# Вызов $http.get в цикле angular.forEach - нарушается порядок элементов

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, get

Возникла проблема добавления в $scope результатов запросов в Angular. 
Я получаю GET-запросом набор элементов типа 1 (items1), и для каждого элемента нужно отправить дополнительный GET-запрос, результат которого записывается в items2. Каждому item1 соответствует свой item2. Если я сразу добавляю item1, а затем отправляю запрос для его статуса и после этого добавляю item2, на странице теряется соответствие item1 <-> item2, т.к. они добавляются в разное время. Если же я делаю вот так:

```
MyApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.items1 = [];
    $scope.items2 = [];
    $http.get('api/one').then(function(result) {
        angular.forEach(result.data, function(item){
            $http.get('api/two/' +  item.id + '/', {'item': item.id} )
            .success(function(resp) {
               $scope.items1.push(item);
               if (resp.data.status == "1")
               { 
                 $scope.items2.push(1);
               }     
               else  
               {        
                 $scope.items2.push(0);
               }
            });                        
        });
    });
}]);
```

Т.е. жду, пока получу статус для item1, и добавляю одновременно item1 и  item2 на страницу, их связь сохраняется, но каждый раз при новой загрузке страницы порядок вывода элементов разный, хотя по первому запросу GET список элементов каждый раз передается один и тот же, и порядок не меняется.
Т.е. получается ситуация, когда, например, один раз выводятся:

```
item1_1 + item2_1, item2_1 + item2_2, item5_1 + item5_2, item3_1 + item3_2...
```

Другой раз:

```
item3_1 + item3_1, item2_1 + item2_2, item1_1 + item1_2, item4_1 + item4_2...
```

Если я правильно понимаю, порядок вывода на страницу зависит от порядка в массиве, а массив заполняется по мере получения ответа по запросу GET. Если в первом запросе все данные получаются сразу, то со вторым запросом для статуса возникает проблема. При выводе массивов `$scope.items1` и `$scope.items2` видно, что каждый раз порядок элементов в этих массивах разный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы так и не назвали свою проблему, поэтому я рискнул предположить, что вам нужен порядок на странице такой же как и в массиве, полученном с сервера.

Для этого надо всего лишь вставлять второй элемент в нужное место массива по индексу вместо использования push:

```
MyApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    var items1 = $scope.items1 = [];
    var items2 = $scope.items2 = [];
    $http.get('api/one').then(function(result) {
        angular.forEach(result.data, function(item, index){
            items1[index] = item; // Хотя тут можно было и push использовать
            $http.get('api/two/' +  item.id + '/', {'item': item.id} )
            .success(function(resp) {
                items2[index] = resp.data.status == "1" ? 1 : 0; // А вот тут push использовать уже нельзя.
            });                        
        });
    });
}]);
```

Comment: спасибо громное, все работает. Единственный вопрос - если я использую `.success` вместо `.then` , возникает ошибка - `resp.data undefined`, не подскажете, почему?